# Foursquare Users Details Endpoint Returning 404 Error

Tags: python-3.x, foursquare

I am trying to use the Foursquare Users Details endpoint to retrieve information about different users, but for some reason, I am getting a 404 error. I can't seem to find the cause of this error, so any help would be really appreciated. Here is my code for user "67786428", which you can find their page on Foursquare here: https://foursquare.com/user/67786428.

```
user_id = '67786428' 

url = 'https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/{}?client_id={}&client_secret={}&v={}'.format(user_id, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET, VERSION) # define URL

# send GET request
results = requests.get(url).json()
results
```

and the output is the following:

```
{'meta': {'code': 404,
  'errorType': 'endpoint_error',
  'errorDetail': 'Endpoint not found',
  'requestId': '5e13583c02a172001bbf17c7'},
 'response': {}}
```

1. My client_id and client_secret are working because I am getting results with the venues endpoints.
2. I checked that I didn't hit the limit on API calls.
3. The code used to work before but I am not sure if Foursquare changed their API and now the url has to be built differently, although according to the documentation, the above endpoint should exist.

Answer (score 0):

You need to authenticate. 
https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/configuration/authentication

Try the following url

```
https://api.foursquare.com/v2/users/{}?&oauth_token=(YOUR_TOKEN)
```

Comment: Thanks @Kosuke. I think this applies to web applications. I am not really building any web apps, I am just trying to run userless queries, like the one shown here: https://developer.foursquare.com/docs/api/users/details.